# Getting last record with a certain status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the results that I need for this query.

I am looking for the last record for a dog that has a status of `adopted`. If the last record is `returned`, I don't want that record - only the `adopted` records.
If my table contains these rows:

```
ID   NAME     DATE      STATUS     WANT THIS ONE?
14   Fido    7/1/2014   Adopted    Yes - last record for Fido that is Adopted
13   Elle    6/15/2014  Returned   No - last record for Elle but not Adopted
12   Elle    6/1/2014   Adopted    No - not the last record for Elle
11   Spot    5/30/14    Adopted    Yes - last record for Spot that is Adopted
10   Spot    5/15/2014  Returned   No - not Adopted
9    Spot    5/1/2014   Adopted    No - not the last record for Spot
```

Comment: What if a dog has a record of adopted, but is later returned? Do you want that dog to come back at all?

Comment: Is there a field that uniquely identifies each dog? You have an ID field in your example but it differs for dogs that seem to be the same. ie. "spot" has id 9, 10, 11, etc. If not is there another table that uniquely identifies a dog? Would be a problem if 2 dogs have the same name, otherwise.

Comment: Pretend that the dog name is the ID - I just simplified.  And yes, Brian, the situation of dog is adopted and later returned is shown is the case of Elle above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the latest record for each dog, only where the latest status is 'Adopted':

```
select *
  from tbl t
 where date = (select max(x.date) from tbl x where x.name = t.name)
   and status = 'Adopted'
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2cae/1/0

In this query if the latest record for a dog is anything other than 'Adopted', the dog will not be returned. This matches your desired output, based on the comments you've placed beside the table.

If you want to return the latest 'Adopted' record for each dog (if any):

```
select *
  from tbl t
 where date = (select max(x.date)
                 from tbl x
                where x.name = t.name
                  and x.status = 'Adopted')
```

However both queries are vulnerable to mixing up 2 dogs who have the same name. You should have another table to uniquely identify the dogs that you can join into, and a unique DOG_ID field on this table that references that table.

Comment: Downvoted because it does not return the correct answer for dog Ellie.

Comment: @DanBracuk Then he should use the second query.... I asked for clarification in my comments but did not get a response. I explained both queries above rather clearly...

Comment: @DanBracuk I changed the order of the 2 queries so that the one matching his 'expected' output comes first. Maybe that way you'll get through enough of the answer before posting that it is incorrect.

Comment: This DOES return the right results!  Thanks a million!  Elle should not be returned because the last record for her was a return.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Sorry, I stand corrected. I didn't see you're also checking the name in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (
    select * ,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) rn
    from tbl
) t1 where t1.rn = 1
and status = 'Adopted'
```

or

```
select * from tbl t1
where status = 'Adopted'
and not exists (
    select 1 from tbl t2
    where t2.Name = t1.Name
    and t2.Date > t1.Date
)
```

Comment: np, was just ticked for a minute because brackuk downvoted everyone's answer to the question, and then posted an answer himself that way overcomplicates the problem. The first above -- with the analytic function -- would probably perform best, out of all of ours

Answer (score -1):

For the data you showed in the question, it is pretty tricky.  Let's start with the assumption that dogs can't be adopted in the future.  Something like this should work:

```
select dog, maxAdoptedDate
from (
select adopted.name dog
, isnull(max(returned.date), dateadd(day, 1, getdate())) maxreturnedDate
, max(adopted.date) maxAdoptedDate
from yourTable adopted left join yourTable returned
on adopted.name = returned.name
and returned.status = 'Returned'
and adopted.status = 'Adopted'
where whatever
group by adopted.name) temp
where maxAdoptedDate > maxReturnedDate
and whatever
```

The two whatevers should be the same.  As mentioned in another answer, if two dogs have the same name, you are in trouble.

Comment: I was simplifying.  Each dog actually has an ID in this table, not a name.